# Bottom border on flot floating bar chart

Tags: jquery, flot

I am working with flot.js to create a floating bar chart (i.e., bottom value defined as well as top).

I've noticed that if I set `series.bars.fill` to less than 1, the graph only shows a border on three sides: http://jsfiddle.net/tFy46/3/.

Is it possible to have the border show up on all four sides, and what would I have to do to achieve that?

Comment: This is currently an open issue: https://github.com/flot/flot/issues/632

Comment: @Mark, thank you! I patched my version of flot.js with the "fix" suggested at https://github.com/slieschke/flot/commit/62e85251306b59147415dd7a0d7b8ed5ad3f497f and that did the trick.

Comment: I they are just close to each other. bar width option give you this result http://jsfiddle.net/tFy46/10/

Answer (score 0):

Try that :

```
grid: {
    borderWidth: {top: 1, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 1},
    borderColor: {top: "purple", left: "purple", bottom:"red", right : "purple"} }
```

Comment: He asked for bar borders rather than grid borders.

Answer (score -2):

You can take out all the borders with:

Bars: {lineWidth: 0;}